# Delete files with PHP

Tags: php

I have a list of file paths that I want to delete. I placed the file paths in a plaintext file in the root directory of the server. For example:

**files_to_be_removed.txt**

```
/path/to/bad/file.php
/path/to/another/bad/file.php
```

In the same directory, I have another file:

**remove.php**

```
$handle = @fopen("files_to_be_removed.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        if (unlink($buffer))
            echo $buffer . ' removed.';
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

When I run my script, nothing is output. Simply, the files in the list aren’t being deleted. Why is that?

Comment: Echo the $buffer variable in your while loop, then you'll see which file it's trying to delete?

Comment: Do you have all the correct permissions in those folders and for those files?

Comment: @DanyCaissy Yes, I tried that, and it echoes the correct filename.

Comment: @bottleboot I’m not sure. Maybe that’s where I should start. Thanks.

Comment: The corrected filename sure, but what about the correct path relative to your project?

Comment: Yeah, when I have problems like this, it usually a permission issue.

Comment: I would try [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) maybe you have the wrong path. Also I would just use `$files = file('remove.txt');` instead of `fopen...`, it will give you an array, just loop through it !

Comment: actually `I have a list of file paths that I want to delete.` if that's the objective (i.e. a one time activity) why don't you just put "rm " infront of each line and execute it? `$ . files_to_be_removed.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$files = file('files_to_be_removed.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (@unlink($file)) {
        echo $file, ' removed', PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        $error = error_get_last();
        echo 'Couldn\'t remove ', $file, ': ', $error['message'], PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing files are not being deleted because "you already have a LOCK on it" [just a guess] -- since you open it and check it's content.
You can avoid all the stress and simply adjust your entire script to a few lines:

```
foreach($filepaths as $filepath){
    $status = @unlink($filepath);
    #the @ is there for error suppression -- in case the file doesn't exist
    if($status){
        #do what you want -- it was successful
    }
}
```